# Two bibliography using thebibliography

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, naming

I was happy with using `\begin{thebibliography} \bibitem \end{thebibliography}` (at the end of chapters of my thesis). I have added a new bibliography with continuous numbering (Manually numbering) at the end of my appendices(after some pages of ending of chapters).

In the first bibliography, I converted my title from Bibliography to References (I used `\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}`) but in second bibliography I want title as "References (Cont.)". How can I do that?

FYI: I didn't call any file for references. I wrote all of them manually using `\bibitem`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Thanks for reply and suggestion. As I am first time posting a query I was not aware of this.

Comment: Would `\renewcommand{\bibname}{References (Cont.)}` work for you? This would be followed by `\begin{thebibliography}` etc.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Mico you can redefine the name of references in front of the environment. This can be achieved by:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References (Cont.)}
```